# Particle System with different geometries

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to implement a point cloud that uses different geometries (e.g. circle, triangle) and not the default plane geometry?

Example with plane geometry: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_random

Another example shows sprites to override the plane geometry but this is not scalable if you want to enlarge the elements. I would like to choose a vector-based approach.

Comment: Those aren't planes, they are just points. You'll need to use sprites to create different shapes.

Comment: You are right but sprites are not suitable for my use case. Sprites doesn't scale. Is there a possibility to create sprites procedural based on defined properties (i.e. size) in WebGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean 'plain geometry', not 'plane geometry'? That example you cite just uses THREE.Geometry.

But to answer your question you could create a SphereGeometry (or whatever geometry you want) and grab the vertices from the mesh and use those to position your particles. You don't need to add the SphereGeometry to the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. The displayed points of the PointCloud look like the [PlaneGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/PlaneGeometry) but i would look to use different geometries. I'm fine with the positioning but not with the appearance of the elements. There is an example to use sprites to change the appearance of the points but they won't scale. I was thinking about using a possibility to draw sprites based specified parameters or to use the derived classes of the Geometry class. Currently, the PointCloud only supports points and not more complex geometries.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. You can indeed use the 'program' option of ParticleCanvasMaterial to render other 2d shapes. More here: http://creativejs.com/tutorials/three-js-part-1-make-a-star-field/. But this is just for the Canvas Renderer. For WebGLRenderer I think you must resort to textures and ParticleBasicMaterial.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Thanks for the link.